# index match with wildcards and multiple criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, formula

I have used `INDEX(MATCH())` formulas of this form before, but never with wildcards. Could anyone explain as two why adding in the `A2&"*"` would return an error value? I have checked the data and there definitely should be a match.

The formula is as below:

```
{=INDEX(I1:M1000,MATCH(1,(M1:M1000=Sheet3!B1)*(I1:I1000=A2&"*"),0),2)}
```

Comment: How is your data laid out?  I've done Index/Match with multiple criteria, but the format [is different](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose A2 contains "abc".

You can put a wild card in the search string of a match statement e.g.

```
MATCH(A2&"*",I1:I1000,0)
```

to search for anything beginning with abc, but not in the range that you're searching.

Also, the bracket

```
(I1:I1000=A2&"*")
```

is just comparing each cell in the range I1:I1000 with A2&"*" so in this context it just does a literal match of each cell with "abc*" and the * doesn't work as a wildcard.

You could try using FIND or SEARCH to do a partial match or using LEFT to get the first few characters of the strings in I1:I1000

```
=INDEX(I1:M1000,MATCH(1,(M1:M1000=B1)*(FIND(A2,I1:I1000)=1),0),2)

=INDEX(I1:M1000,MATCH(1,(M1:M1000=B1)*(LEFT(I1:I1000,LEN(A2))=A2),0),2)
```

You could also still use a wildcard if you re-cast the formula using an IF statement:-

```
=INDEX(I1:M1000,MATCH(A2&"*",IF(M1:M1000=B1,I1:I1000),0),2)
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks so much for the help Tom! I seem to be struggling with alot of cross compatability issues of when you can and cant use things lately :/ Thanks again for the tips on this :D:D:D:D

Comment: No problem. It did occur to me later that you could re-cast it using an IF statement and still use a wildcard.

Comment: And omitted a zero from first formula - plz see edit.